# How to display popup in all pages except one with Gatsby?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

Hi i created a popup in my layout and i dont wanna display it only in one page. Is it possible to use some hook or something to turn of the popup just for one page? It would be great if Gatsby have something like that.

I tried location.pathname but it didn't worked.

`const isPrivacyPolicyPage = location.pathname === '/privacy-policy';

```
if (!showPopup || isPrivacyPolicyPage) {
    return null;
}`
```

Comment: You may want to use something like `.includes` to account for changes to the pathname, e.g. `location.pathname.includes("privacy-policy")`

Answer (score 0):

You may do this by passing them as props and using in the other components.